Canvas Submissions Rest API not returning comments consistently
I am using the canvas submissions rest api. My endpoint is as follows:
/api/v1/courses/:courseId/students/submissions?include[]=submission_comments&student_ids[]=all&include[]=rubric_assessment

When I just paste the url into chrome I get the entire object I am expecting. Its a record of a submission with the "submission_comments" and "rubric_assessment" keys present in the return. If I run the same url in postman and in my application I get the data return but those keys are missing.
The data is required for the report I am providing. Has anyone ever run into this issue?
